# How to design the Oozie coordinator on arrival of input multiple times in a day

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have a requirement to schedule my coordinator on arrival of input from other application. I may receive one or multiple times in a day. So, whenever I receive an input I need to trigger my treatment. Can anyone please help me how to do it in Oozie coordinator? I have tried with below code but it runs only once in a day, it is not working even if I receive input after first treatment.

```
    <coordinator-app name="TEST_MASTER_C" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="${start_date}" end="${end_date}" timezone="Europe/Paris" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.2" xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.1">
  <controls>
    <timeout>1430</timeout>
    <execution>FIFO</execution>
  </controls>
  <datasets>
    <dataset name="inputFlag" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" initial-instance="${start_date}" timezone="Europe/Paris">
      <uri-template>@nameNode@/testpath</uri-template>
      <done-flag>${flag}</done-flag>
    </dataset>
  </datasets>
  <input-events>
    <data-in name="coordInputFlag" dataset="inputFlag">
      <instance>${coord:current(0)}</instance>
    </data-in>
  </input-events>
```

Comment: Hi, can anyone please answer?

Comment: Maybe it runs once a day because you told it to? `frequency="${coord:days(1)}"`

Comment: Yes it runs once a day as per my code. but my requirement is to trigger the treatment whenever the input is available in the specified path. That means I may get input once or multiple times in a day. So, in this case, How to handle it in oozie coordinator?

Comment: I don't know if Oozie is a good choice for that... Sounds like you need a system like AWS lambda or use the INotify API in HDFS

Comment: Otherwise, run a script every minute or less, check the files in the "landing zone", process any that exist, blocking the checker script until complete, then delete files once done. If no files exist, keep checking